# Can Netty be configured to use OCSP?

Tags: java, netty, ocsp

I currently use Netty 3.9.5 and I want to use OCSP (Online Certificate Status Protocol) to verify a PKI certificate.  I have only found Java examples using a local keystore to check the authentication of a certificate.  Since I am new to the SSL/TLS world, I am hoping that this is a lack of knowledge on my part.  Does Netty 3.x or 4.x support the use of OCSP or is this something I will need to add myself?  Are there any NIO frameworks that support OCSP?

Comment: Sample TrustManager code for Netty for OCSP validation is mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/q/34140869/1514850

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add this yourself by implementing the javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory interface which will do the OCSP validation. There is some code in this [class here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/security/provider/certpath/OCSP.java.html) you maybe able to use to do the OCSP validation.

If you take a look at the Netty [HttpSnoopClient.java](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/3.9/src/main/java/org/jboss/netty/example/http/snoop/HttpSnoopClient.java) example it shows you how to register your custom ssl TrustManager in line 65.